# apache 2.4 with basic authentication and fail2ban apache-auth

Tags: apache-2.4, fail2ban

It seems I have a conflict in my configuration on CentOS 7 server.

The issue appears between vhost configuration on apache 2.4 (httpd) with the basic authentication and fail2ban apache-auth banning feature.

I want two things :

1) An authentication for access to my each websites with basic authentication feature.

2) Ban IP with fail2ban from apache errorlog files.

My problem is :

- If I have "Deny from all" in location tag inside of vhost configuration file so I have prompt for authentication but I have too lot of errors in apache errorlog file --> "AH01797: client denied by server configuration"
- However, if I change "Deny from all" by "Require all granted", the issue dispears but the prompt authentication too obviously.

How can I have this two features together, without conflict?

I hope this is clear. Please ask for any additional information needed.

Answer (score 0):

> I hope this is clear.

Well not really. Either the issue is that fail2ban doesn't recognize `AH01797: client denied` but you want it'd happen (then see P.1), or vice versa it find that but you don't want that (then see P.2)

1. Normally fail2ban's apache-auth should detect this kind of failures.
   If it does not either your fail2ban version (or config file) are too old, or you've some different log (compare it with [this](https://github.com/nickweeds/fail2ban/blob/2c158fe16890b9e9f98a3428cc009f792618ba75/fail2ban/tests/files/logs/apache-auth#L17) or provide an example of your log).
2. If you want that fail2ban ignores this, just open /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-auth.conf (make a backup) and remove the rule for this, for example for [newest version](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/d1a73d30046e0bfbdf932dfaa0c4e7168873008e/config/filter.d/apache-auth.conf#L27) it would be something like this:

```
- failregex = ^client (?:denied by server configuration|used wrong authentication scheme)\b
+ failregex = ^client (?:used wrong authentication scheme)\b
```

Comment: Thanks sebres, It's perfect. I'm concerne by P.2. I commented the line "^client (?:denied by server configuration|used wrong authentication scheme)\b" in /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-auth.conf file at "failregex" argument level.